# android- How to stop music when the app is on background?

Tags: android

I am developing an app with four activities. When the app is opened, I am playing a background music which should continue be playing for all the activities. But when the app goes to background, the music should pause and when the app resume, the music should continue again.

Please suggest the best way to achieve this.

Thanks,
Anand.

Comment: I think your app should register for Audio Focus events in addition to the lifecycle events for the activities. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html#audiofocus

Comment: Thanks iago for reply but Audio Focus is not to identify the app status. We can stop or start music in several ways including Audio Focus but knowing the app status in multi activity app is more important here I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anand, you need to stop your music, when activity goes to background.

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
super.onPause();
  //stop or pause your music here.
}
```

and you need to play your music, when activity resumes.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
   // play your music here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you are playing the music. The answer is almost certainly to use the lifecycle methods. For the activity, I think the best methods to override are onResume and onPause. These methods are called when an activity appears in the foreground, and gets hidden respectively. Services have their own lifecycle, but it behaves in a different way.

Edit: Just read the question more closely. To do this between multiple activities, the music should be played via a bound service. By being selective about where the service is bound and unbound, it will stay alive between activity transitions. I think that when a new activity is created, onResume is called before on pause. So, you bind the service to the new activity in onResume, and unbind it from the old one in onPause. When the activitys are closed, the same methods are called, but on the opposite activities.

Edit 2: You could also bind the activity to the service in onCreate and onDestroy. This would cause the service to persist until all activity are removed by the OS, or the app is closed. This would mean that you would also need play and pause methods on the service, and a mechanism to ensure that only the correct activity can call them. Perhapse, when you call the playMusic function, you can provide an object to act as a token. When you call pause or stop, you provide that token again. The result will be that only the activity that called play most recently can stop the music, and all activities call play when they bind to the service, or when onResume is called.